# service build modal in nz ,nzVisible is always true , is it right

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

```html
public show(args?:any):void{
        this._privateArgs=args;
        this.isVisible=true;
        this.tplModal = this._modalService.create({
            nzTitle: this.tplTitle,
            nzContent: this.tplContent,
            nzFooter: this.tplFooter,
            nzMaskClosable: false,
            nzVisible:false,
            nzClosable: false,
            nzStyle:{ top: '20px' },
            nzMask:true,
            nzWidth:this.nzWidth,
            nzOkLoading:this.nzOkLoading,
            nzCancelLoading:this.nzCancelLoading
        });
        
        this.tplModal.afterOpen.subscribe(r=>{
            this.init();
            this.onShown();
        })
        this.tplModal.afterClose.subscribe(r=>{
            this.onClose();
        })
        this.tplModal.open();
       this.onOpen();
       
    }
```

[nzVisible is always true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23JXv.png)

I just want build modal  by service and control modal open by myself  ,but  set nzVisible :false not work ,